# Excel Vba - Add LastModified user and LastUpdated Date

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to record the lastUpdatedDate and LastModifiedUser of those who made any changes to the rows of record. I can't seems to get the 2 to work together and it always result in Excel freezing.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Row > 1 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, "E") = Date()
    Cells(Target.Row, "F") = Environ("username")

End Sub
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch off `events` when you wright back to excel sheet. Without that you get infinite loop (you writhe to excel which triggers event again >> which write to excel >> which trigger event again >> and so on...) . Your code after changes will look like below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

application.EnableEvents = false
    If Target.Row > 1 Then
        Cells(Target.Row, "E") = Date()
        Cells(Target.Row, "F") = Environ("username")
    End if
application.EnableEvents = true
End Sub
```

Comment: omg thanks it works! Did not know that this will trigger an infinite loop. Thanks alot!